# random or garbled text on IIS when producing PDFs

Tags: asp.net, iis

IIS 7
asp.net site
VB 2015

We have 30 users using a web facing asp.net  site where they select from a list of procedures a patient had performed.  It is supposed to then create an invoice with patient details,  the procedures they selected and the pricing.

Randomly once a day it starts to generate the reports with random text or missing letters in the pdf it generates.

Nobody can generate an invoice properly until IIS is reset.

An IIS reset clears the issue for the next day or so.

Any ideas to prevent this from happening and what exactly is the issue if you know?

[missing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J3Kl.jpg)
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJ2J.jpg)

Comment: Are you using any third party library for generating pdf files? Also, please add a screenshot of garbled text

Comment: Added images to the post.   We are using Telerik.

Comment: When this problem start appearing, is there any page to verify that data returned from database is still correct and it is just pdf rendering issue? Also, have you guys noticed any pattern that some specific characters are missed?

Comment: yes the data from the db is perfect.  As soon as the IIS reset is performed they click generate again and its as it should.  It removes random letters or omits compete numbers and sometimes adds in random letters.

Comment: Not everyone has access to Telerik controls to reproduce it. Please contact Telerik customer support.